# able to run unsigned app on jailbroken iOS

Tags: ios, code-signing, jailbreak

I'm developing an app for jailbroken iOS devices using Xcode 4.3 (altered by JailCoder), testing on an iPod Touch 4G, currently running iOS 5.1.1, previously 5.0.1. I noticed recently I'm able to run my app on my iPod without using either `ldid` or a self-signing certificate with `codesign` to bypass code-signing requirements (as described on http://www.saurik.com/id/8). I *don't* have either the `security.mac.proc_enforce` or `security.mac.vnode_enforce` security checks disabled.

So why would I be able to run unsigned code on my iPod? This didn't seem to change when I upgraded from 5.0.1 to 5.1.1. My beta testers are unable to run my app on their 5.1.1 systems when not signed with a self-signing certificate. What could be different on my system? Could it be differing methods we used to jailbreak our devices?

Comment: We don't tend to downvote because of jailbreaking. There are a lot of JB developers around here, for example chpwn, KennyTM, and myself.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that too, and actually am planning on linking to one of your libraries, libipodimport, in my app. But progress is stalled due to problems I'm having with code signing.

Comment: Do you have Appsync installed?

Comment: @grasGendarme: not currently, but it was installed while I had iOS 5.0.1. (The two beta testers reporting problems have it installed.)

Comment: I still don't know what the problem was here exactly, but an answer is not at the top of my wish list anymore. @grasGendarme: if you put your comment in an answer, I'll accept as the best possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iOS 5.1.1 jailbreak didn't patch the code signing need to run executables. AFAIK no one apparently cared enough to do so, which means many discomfort for those who build *on* iOS some software as ./configure scripts obviously doesn't work. If an executable is not codesigned (or fake-codesigned), it will receive a SIGKILL.

Answer (score 3):

To run unsigned code on an iDevice, it needs to be [jailbroken](http://jailbrea.kr/). To easily install your custom app and debug it from Xcode (or give it to somebody else) the easiest way is to package an IPA and sync it via iTunes. However, it requires AppSync (mainly used for piracy, sadly).

Comment: @LeoTh3o's answer seems quite plausible, so I'm gonna switch accepted answers. But I +1'd yours so you wouldn't lose too much.